# Анонимная доставка ключей в p2p-сетях

Tags: p2p

Я разрабатываю p2p-чат в качестве школьного проекта и использую идеи Tox Core как пример. Я уже закончил и протестил Kademlia DHT для организации сети и поиска узлов. 
Но проблема в том, что DHT id и идентификационные ключи - разные вещи. DHT id случайно генерируется каждый раз, когда приложение запускается.
Tox использует луковую маршрутизацию для доставки ключей. Как я понял из доков, пакет оборачивается в несколько слоёв щифрования и затем отправляется через набор случайно взятых узлов. Самый спорный момент возникает в моменте, когда пакет достигает конечного узла в цепи. Как я понял, последний узел распространяет это сообщение по всей сети, пока не найдёт получателя. И хотя это воглядит вполне даже рабочим методом, это же достаточно сложный и неэффективный способ? Поправьте, если не прав.
Какой наилучший способ вы можете предложить, чтобы доставить свой публичный ключ другому узлу, чей публичный ключ мы также знаем, но не знаем ни DHT id, ни ip-адреса, и при этом остаться анонимным? 
Для ясности, я пишу всё на c++ и boost::asio. В конце, я скомпилю этот код и буду использовать как модуль для electron (использовать qt сроки не позволяют).

EDIT:

Я внимательно перечитал доки. На самом деле, последний узел не рассылает всем сообщение. Он просто сохраняет его у себя в памяти. Последний узел в цепи выбирается как имеющий наиболее близкий к нашему открытому ключу id (в xor метрике, конечно). Потом узел, кому мы изначально доставляли это сообщение, выполняет аналогичный поиск и берёт значение.
Но вопрос об эффективности остаётся открытым.